# Why does priority queue (max heap) in C++ use less<T> instead of greater<T>?

Tags: c++, heap, priority-queue

I am confused as to why the [priority_queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/) in C++ uses [less](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/less/) as a default comparator and implement a max heap ? Doesn't less arrange the elements in ascending order ?

Answer (score 1):

For consistency.  `less` is used as the default comparator for many algorithms and containers, and us mere humans don't have to try and remember which one uses which comparator by default since they are all the same.

Comment: So you mean greater would be a logical default comparator ?

Comment: No. Everywhere else the STL needs a comparison it defaults to less.

Comment: Okay, irrespective of the default to less, logically shouldn't it be greater ?

Comment: @Viraj If you want a min heap, yes.  If you want a max heap, no.  `priority_queue` is just a queue and doesn't know what you want to do with it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean. To rephrase my question, if less used as a comparator to sort a vector, sorts it in ascending order, why is it used in a priority queue to return a max element first (max heap).

Comment: If consistency of using `less` was the reason, they could have made the default implementation of `priority_queue` to behave like `min heap` using `less` instead of the non-intuitive `max heap` using `less`. My point is there must be some other reason/constraint.